# How to get X-Forwarded-For(IP) header on passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm have a route to authenticate logins and i need to compare the current user access IP with the user IP that was registered.

```js
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/index',
  failureRedirect: '/login?fail=true'
 })
)
```

On my `auth.js` file i have this...

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy

module.exports = passport => {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: 'username',
      passwordField: 'password',
      passReqToCallback: true
    },
    (req, username, password, done) => {
      console.log(req.headers)
      findUser(username, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err)
        }

        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false)
        }

        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isValid) => {
          if (err) return done(err)
          if (!isValid) return done(null, false)
          return done(null, user)
        })
       })
      }
    )
  )
}
```

The `x-forwarded-for` key on req in callback is `undefined`, so I check the `headers` and I saw that the `x-forwarded-for` is not present.
how can I get it?

`

Comment: do you have a proxy in the middle?

Comment: no i don't have

Comment: `x-forwarded-for` is generally set by reverse proxies

Comment: well, i don't know much about but in my searches on google(and here) it's recommends get the request.header('x-forwarded-for') when you need the client ip

Comment: so you know a users ip shouldn't really be used for authentication. it can change.

Comment: it's not an authentication, just a verification like Google's email or Facebook when someone else accesses your account.